# How to define colour name by string to use in linecolour lc, not working gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

The following code does not produce any error but it just ouptut a grey line,

```
col2="#cd0000"
p x w l lc col2
```

while this one gives a red line as it should

```
p x w l lc "#cd0000"
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: as far as I understand  `help colorspec` your second example should not give a red line. Which version of gnuplot are running?

Comment: @theozh `"#cd0000"` is a valid colorspec since it has the form `"#RRGGBB"` i.e. 6 hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: @ProgMetalSlug according to the manual `rgb "#RRGGBB"` would be a valid `<colorspec>` but not `"#RRGGBB"` alone. But apparently `lc "#RRGGBB"`  works as well. But then it is not logic to me why `lc col2` will not give red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `help colorspec`. You can also insert `rgb`. This will also give a red line.

```
col2 = "#cd0000"
plot x w l lc rgb col2
```

From `help colorspec`:

> Syntax:
>
> ```
>   ... {linecolor | lc} {"colorname" | <colorspec> | <n>}
> ```
>
> where `<colorspec>` has one of the following forms:
>
> ```
>   rgbcolor "colorname"    # e.g. "blue"
>   rgbcolor "0xRRGGBB"     # string containing hexadecimal constant
>   rgbcolor "0xAARRGGBB"   # string containing hexadecimal constant
>   rgbcolor "#RRGGBB"      # string containing hexadecimal in x11 format
>   rgbcolor "#AARRGGBB"    # string containing hexadecimal in x11 format
>   rgbcolor <integer val>  # integer value representing AARRGGBB
>   rgbcolor variable       # integer value is read from input file
> ```

- `"#cd0000"` is not a valid color name, like `"red"`, `"green"`, `"blue"`
- `"#cd0000"` is not a valid colorspec
- `"#cd0000"` is a string which cannot be interpreted as a number, then it looks like gnuplot will take 0, which is black.